# How do I use PHP preg_replace with the same pattern, when the word happens multiple times?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Sorry that my question is so horribly worded, but I have no idea how to state it as a question. It is easier for me to just show code and explain.

I am trying to write a function to allow for tagging of words. We have database of words we call glossary. I want to take a large amount of text and look for multiple instance of `[G]some word/words here[/G]`. Then I want to replace that with `<a href="viewglossary.php?word={WORD/WORDS BETWEEN [G][/G]}">{WORD/WORDS BETWEEN [G][/G]}</a>`

Here is my current function:

```
function getGlossary($str)
{
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[]='/\[G\](.*)\[\/G\]/';
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[]='<a href="viewglossary.php?word=$1">$1</a>';
    return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
}
echo getGlossary($txt);
```

If I only do a single instance of the `[G][/G]` tag it works.

```
$txt='What you need to know about [G]beans[/G]';
```

This will output

```
What you need to know about <a href="viewglossary.php?word=beans">beans</a>
```

However this

```
$txt='What you need to know about [G]beans[/G] and [G]corn[/G]';
```

will output

```
What you need to know about <a href="viewglossary.php?word=beans[/G] and [G]corn">beans[/G] and [G]corn</a>
```

I am sure I have something wrong in my pattern. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like a job for preg_replace_**all**

Comment: did you want to replace corn also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your dot-star lazy: `.*?`

- Without the `?` to keep the `.*` in check, the `.*` will eat up all characters up to the final `[/G]`
- the `*` quantifier is greedy, so the `.*` starts off by matching all the characters in the string up to the very end. Then it backtracks only as far as needed to allow the  `[/G]` to match (therefore, it only backtracks to the last  `[/G]`).
- the `?` makes quantifiers "lazy", so that they only match as far as needed for the rest of the regex to match. Therefore it will only match up to the first  `[/G]`.

Modify your regex like so:

```
$pattern = "~\[G\](.*?)\[/G\]~";
```

Note that to make the regex easier to read, I have changed the delimiter and unescaped the forward slash, as there is no need to escapes slashes unless the delimiter is a slash. Common delimiters include `~`, `%`, `@`, `#`... But really tildes are the most beautiful. :)

**Reference**

- [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)
- [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)